# Is it impossible to destroy depot by ship photon cannon only?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I got a mission to destroy a [depot](https://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Depot) on a planet. Therefore I flew to the marked position and destroyed the depot from far away with the [photon cannon](https://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Photon_Cannon) in my starship. Unfortunately, the mission don't turn to "solved".

Is there a "minimal requirement" to get such a mission solved, like "shoot at least one shot with your [boltcaster](https://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Boltcaster)"? Or do I have to land first and use the nearby savepoint?

Answer (score 3):

It's not entirely clear, although a few players have come to some pretty sound conclusions.

As per this [post](https://steamcommunity.com/app/275850/discussions/0/1762482479181969647/), some players have been able to destroy supply depots with their starship and successfully hand in the quest. Others reported experiencing issues similar to yours, where they destroyed the containers (with their ship) but weren't able to complete the mission.

This [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/NoMansSkyTheGame/comments/92wxpa/destroying_supply_depot_missions_bugged_if/) was the most helpful one when I encountered this issue. In addition to ensuring you have inventory space in your starship, try landing first and "discovering" the containers, shooting them with your boltcaster, then jumping back in your ship and destroying them. Some users think that you have to "experience" the new wave of sentinels before you can take to your ship to finish the rest. Once I started doing this I didn't have any problems handing in the mission.

If none of this works, the only other recommendation I can make is to ensure there isn't some other condition you're not meeting (e.g., deliver 200 gold to an NPC). Otherwise, you might just have to chalk it up to these missions being incredibly buggy.